# Kendo Grid Edit - Dates not getting to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Using Kendo UI with MVC3.

Using the network tab on developer tool, I can see all the correct data is being sent, but when I hover over the model parameter that is coming into the controller method, the dates are all 1/1/0001.  Here is some data:

Header info from network request tab (shows the correct data is going to the controller:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://localhost:47621
Referer:http://localhost:47621/NewOrder/Detail/18
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko)                   Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
CommentId:9
CommentText:blah blah random text.
IncidentId:7
ModifiedBy:admin
ModifiedDate:Thu Jun 06 2013 08:15:08 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
CreatedBy:admin
CreatedDate:Thu Jun 06 2013 08:15:08 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

kendo code:

```
var IncId = $("#IncidentId").val();
var ds_CommentsGrid = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read        : {
            url     : '@Url.Action("JsonGetComments", "TrespassOrder")/' + IncId,
            dataType: 'json',
            type    : "POST"
        },
        update      : {
            url     : '@Url.Action("JsonEditComment", "TrespassOrder")',
            dataType: 'json',
            type    : "POST"
        },
        parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
            if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                var values = {};
                values["CommentId"] = options.models[0].CommentId;
                values["CommentText"] = options.models[0].CommentText;
                values["IncidentId"] = options.models[0].IncidentId;
                values["ModifiedBy"] = options.models[0].ModifiedBy;
                values["ModifiedDate"] = options.models[0].ModifiedDate;
                values["CreatedBy"] = options.models[0].CreatedBy;
                values["CreatedDate"] = options.models[0].CreatedDate;
                return values;
            }
        }
    },
    batch    : true,
    schema   : {
        model: {
            id    : "CommentId",
            fields: {
                CommentId   : { editable: false },
                CommentText : { editable: true },
                CreatedDate : { editable: false, type: "date"},
                ModifiedDate: { editable: false, type: "date" },
                CreatedBy   : { editable: false },
                ModifiedBy  : { editable: false }
            }
        }
    },
    pageSize : 5
});

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#Comment-List").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: ds_CommentsGrid,
        sortable  : true,
        filterable: { extra: false, operators: {
            string: { startswith: "Starts with", eq: "Is equal to" }
        }
        },
        pageable  : true,
        columns   : [
            { field: "CommentText", title: "Comment", width: 300, filterable: false },
            { field: "CreatedBy", title: "Author", filterable: false },
            { field: "CreatedDate", title: "Original Date", format: "{0:g}", filterable: { ui: "datetimepicker" } },
            { field: "ModifiedBy", title: "Edited By", filterable: false },
            { field: "ModifiedDate", title: "Editted On", format: "{0:g}", filterable: { ui: "datetimepicker" } },
            { command: ["edit"], title: "Actions" }
        ],
        editable  : "popup"
    });
});
```

I am wondering about the content type as noted in the request header, is it correct?

Comment: Seems to be a problem parsing the dates sent as string in the server.

Comment: Using the Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded, is that a string or an object?  If it is a string, should I change the controller parameter to a string array or something?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the response as json:

```
    update: {
        url     : '@Url.Action("JsonEditComment", "TrespassOrder")',
        dataType: 'json',
        type    : "POST",
        contentType: "application/json"
    },
    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
            var values = {};
            values["CommentId"] = options.models[0].CommentId;
            values["CommentText"] = options.models[0].CommentText;
            values["IncidentId"] = options.models[0].IncidentId;
            values["ModifiedBy"] = options.models[0].ModifiedBy;
            values["ModifiedDate"] = options.models[0].ModifiedDate;
            values["CreatedBy"] = options.models[0].CreatedBy;
            values["CreatedDate"] = options.models[0].CreatedDate;
            return JSON.stringify(values);
        }
    }
```

ASP.NET MVC can't parse the string representation of a JavaScript Date object. However it can parse it when it is serialized as JSON.